# How to delete all Xcom after a run?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am kind of new to airflow and I can not seem to find a way to delete all my Xcom after a run. I found the bash command airflow clear, but this deleted task instances as well and I just want the Xcom cleared. Any help is welcomed. Thanks!

Update:

```
clear_xcom_operator = SqliteOperator(
    task_id="clear_Xcom",
    sqlite_conn_id="sqlite_default",
    sql="delete from xcom where dag_id='dumper'",
    retries=0,
    dag=dag,
)
```

I am doing this but I get the error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: xcom

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your sqlite_default connection and ensure that your actual db file (in ~/airflow) is specified.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a functionality to clear XCOM that is provided out of the box. Probably, the only ways is to manipulate the backend database directly, by deleting the entries in the `xcom` table based on `dag_id`.

XCOM is not meant to exchange large amounts of data between tasks. So, if space considerations is the reason for deleting XCOM values, a better solution would be to avoid using XCOM and write out the data to a shared storage.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I am aware that the Xcom is not made for sharing large values, but in my current architecture I am a little obliged to use them this way. I will change this in the  future. I am trying to delete the Xcom table based in the dag id, but it seems I can not do it.